# How can I see faces in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces

I wanted to make hair on his head which I was going to select faces on top of his head and duplicate so I can place it over his head but I only can see this box and can select this box.

[image]

How can I see the tiny faces not box?

Answer (score 1):

Your object is still a cube, you've given it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, which makes it look like a sphere with a lot of faces, but this roundness and these faces are only virtual. If you want your object to really be round with all these faces, apply the modifier:

[image]